# How to incorporate all of my c# project file to .sln and get IntelliSense?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm beginning tutorial for C# programming on Visual Studio Code. My first project folder (.csproj & etc) created works well with .sln and showing helps and suggestion from IntelliSense such as suggesting overloaded method and red squiggly line. But for consequent .csproj folder created, feature from IntelliSense mentioned above doesn't work.

[1st test project that only work with .sln](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyFe7.png)
[2nd/consequent test project that doesnt work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfnkV.png)

From the .sln code, it seems it only direct/incorporate the first project's .csproj GUID from picture below but i hit dead end here.
[.sln code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwyul.png)

May i know how to incorporate every .csproj to have full function of .sln/IntelliSense? Many thanks!
//kindly excuse my non-native english

Comment: Found out by right click folder name under "Solution Explorer" and choose "Add Existing Project..." will incorporate any existing .csproj to be working with IntelliSense.

Comment: Write up your answer and accept it.  It's perfectly OK to answer your own question.  That way if someone finds your question, there's an answer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out by right click folder name under "Solution Explorer" and choose "Add Existing Project..." will incorporate any existing .csproj to be working with IntelliSense.[image: as below]

Comment: Accept this as the answer if it is the solution to your problem.

Comment: Will do. 24hours mark required for it.